# How do I disable video information on gdm3 login screen?

Tags: gdm3, login-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE Plasma DE and gdm3 login manager.

When I open my laptop lid, the login screen shows the title and control buttons for some recent video that I was watching in my browser (Firefox 106 and recent versions, if it matters).  I kind of don't want to worry about everyone near me having a good view of whatever pornography I was watching yesterday every time I open my laptop.  How do I disable this feature?  The DE only has settings for the SDDM login screen, which I'm not using.

As a side question, who in God's name thought this would be a desireable feature?

Comment: comment about side question... not everyone watches porn

Comment: Even without porn, it's a terrible idea.  login and unlock screens shouldn't leak **ANY** information about users (and, yeah, drop down menus and other lists of user names on the login screen are a dumb idea too - they give away half of the username/password combination).

Comment: @jsotola Okay, so I was watching videos of cats pushing things off of tables.  The question's still valid: What conceivable purpose does it serve to have my login screen document the fact that the last video I watched was cats pushing things off tables?

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right ... I wasn't thinking